# Render Images from wikipedia api with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, wikipedia

I´m trying to render the images of a wikipedia article.

for e.g. from https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appendizitis

To avoid the cross-origin-policy, I use a proxy:

```
function imageWp() {

var word = 'Appendizitis';

$.ajaxPrefilter( function (options) {
  if (options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {
    var https = (window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'http:' : 'https:');
    options.url = https + '//cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + options.url;
  }
});

$.get(
    'https://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&section=0&page=' + word + '&callback=?',
    function (response) {
        console.log("> ", response);
        $("#viewer").html(response);
});
}
```

How can i parse only the images?
Or, is there a better way with javascript, jquery and ajax? I don´t want to use PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function imageWp() {

    var word = 'Appendizitis';

    $.ajaxPrefilter(function (options) {
        if (options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {
            var https = (window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'http:' : 'https:');
            options.url = https + '//cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + options.url;
        }
    });

    $.get(
        'https://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&section=0&page=' + word + '&callback=?',

    function (response) {
        var m;
        var urls = [];
        var regex = /<img.*?src=\\"(.*?)\\"/gmi;

        while (m = regex.exec(response)) {
            urls.push(m[1]);
        }

        urls.forEach(function (url) {
            $("#viewer").append('<img src="' + window.location.protocol + url + '">');
        });
    });
}

imageWp();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="viewer"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use regex to extract what I want from the response.

Something like this:

```
$.get(
    'https://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&section=0&page=' + word + '&callback=?',
    function (response) {
        var resp = $.parseJSON(response);
        var text = resp.parse.text['*'];
        re = /img.*?src="(.*?)"/g
        while( match = re.exec(text)) { 
           console.log(match[1]); 
        }
});
```

In match[1] you are going to have the "src" attribute of the image. This code is not perfect, but it should show you what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Wikipedia API:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aApiSandbox#action=query&prop=images&format=json&titles=Appendicitis&uselang=de

You can query an article and get a list of images back in JSON:

```
{
    "warnings": {
        "query": {
            "*": "..."
        }
    },
    "query-continue": {
        "images": {
            "imcontinue": "70980|Stomach_colon_rectum_diagram-en.svg"
        }
    },
    "query": {
        "pages": {
            "70980": {
                "pageid": 70980,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Appendicitis",
                "images": [
                    {
                        "ns": 6,
                        "title": "File:Acute Appendicitis.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "ns": 6,
                        "title": "File:Acute appendicitis High Power.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "ns": 6,
                        "title": "File:Appendicitis - low mag.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "ns": 6,
                        "title": "File:Appendicitis world map - DALY - WHO2004.svg"
                    },
                    {
                        "ns": 6,
                        "title": "File:Appendix-Entfernung.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "ns": 6,
                        "title": "File:CAT scan demonstrating acute appendicitis.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "ns": 6,
                        "title": "File:Commons-logo.svg"
                    },
                    {
                        "ns": 6,
                        "title": "File:Inflamed appendix.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "ns": 6,
                        "title": "File:SonoAppendizitis.JPG"
                    },
                    {
                        "ns": 6,
                        "title": "File:Stitches post appendicitis surgery.jpg"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```